# Adding limit with variable causing error SQL syntax

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I want to add `limit` dynamically with variable, but it gave me an error. something like this:

routes/api/post.js

```js
..
// req.params.limit = 3
const limit = req.params.limit

models.post
   .findAll({
      subQuery: false,
      order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
      include: ["post_picture", "tags"],
      limit
   })
..
```

gave me an error

```js
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the 
right syntax to use near ''3'' at line 1
```

If I set manually `limit: 3` it works, but that will be a nightmare for pagination. Is this a bug or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the `limit` to number, because its type is `string`

```js
const limit = parseInt(req.params.limit);
```